# Programatically Updating A Categories Parent ID

Tags: magento-1.9, category, database, category-tree, upgrade-script

I am currently in the process of reordering an entire category tree via an upgrade script. I am aware that you can update the parent ID via the following:

```
$category->setParentId($value);
$category->save();
```

Is this the right method to carry out this update?

In doing this will the path and children_count values in the catalog_category_entity table auto update or will I have to set these before saving the category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will suffice or is a correct way to do it.
If you look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController::moveAction()` you will see what happens when you update category position by drag and drop from admin.

Most interesting parts are `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::move()` and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category::changeParent()`

Hope this helps.